# Does custom property handler indexing work on network drives?

Tags: shell, winapi, networking, indexing, properties

[According to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-wds-extidx-propertyhandlers#troubleshooting-property-handlers), in order for Windows search to index custom properties, the property handler dll and any custom .propdesc file need to be registered from specific locations on a user's machine. So is custom property indexing possible on network drives, and if so, how might it be done given those constraints? Thank you very much for any input.

Comment: Don't mix property handler concept with protocol handler concept. Protocol handler will know how to get the data/content (streams), from network drives (or not), and property handler will extract custom properties (if .dll and .propdesc are registered). All that happens on the PC where indexing process runs.

Comment: Oh, I thought the network drive conducts indexing itself, but perhaps I'm confused.

Comment: You can (could?) do that for libraries I think https://www.cloudtec.ch/blog/tech/2015/add-search-indexed-network-share-windows-library. If you configure search on the server this way, then you'll have to register the dll and .propdesc on the server too.